# How to fire a change event for html input type=range when slider value is same as initial value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an html input type=range slider like this:

`<input type="range" min="0" max="5" step="0.1" value="0" class="slider" id="aroma-slider" (input)="trackInput($event, 'aroma')" (change)="slideDone($event, 'aroma')">`

My events are firing great EXCEPT if the user drags the slider all the way down to 0, then the `change` event is not fired, even though the user has interacted with the slider and moved it. I assume it is because the slider value is the same as the original slider value in the `value` attribute. How do I trigger a change event when the starting value and ending value of the slider happen to be the same? In my use case the user selecting a `0` value is valid.

Comment: It seems to be working right here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re15vk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The (input) event is firing fine, but NOT the (change) event, if the value == 0.

Comment: It fires if you slide and select any other value and then slide back to 0. Tested it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3zmdw

Comment: ... on the first slide, I mean. dragging the slider thumb over to any value greater than 0, then without letting go, sliding back to 0.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But if the user drags the slider and puts it back to the 'zero' value on the first slide, it does not fire. :(

Comment: Oh, that's because the component's value didn't changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work-around by listening to all `mouseup` and `touchend` events, then filtering to only act on the ones that happen on the slider:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="5" step="0.1" value="0" class="slider" id="aroma-slider" (input)="trackInput($event, 'aroma')" (change)="slideDone($event, 'aroma')">

$(document).on('mouseup touchend', (e:Event)=> {
    if ( $(e.target).attr('class') == 'slider' &&  $(e.target).val() == 0 ) {
        this.slideDone(e, 'aroma');
    }
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing angular and jquery. Just add the events (mouseup)="..." and (touchend)="". It's less code than adding jquery as you did above.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4k3cdu?file=src/app/app.component.html